# Sticky Header Jumps up to Top of Screen in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari, viewport

I'm building a website with a sticky header. When you start to scroll past the header, the top of the screen will catch it and stick it to the top of the screen. It will follow you after you scroll past it. See http://cupofjoseph.biz/index2.html for an example or see code below.

When scrolling in Safari on an iPhone 5 (holding phone vertically), the sticky header will jump up to the top of the screen before the top of the screen reaches it.

I would like to make the sticky header seamlessly stick to the top of the screen instead of jump up.

Does anybody know why the sticky nav is behaving like this and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks all.

This works in Chrome on the same phone. I have run into other issues in safari where the window height might be being evaluated erroneously in Safari, so that's my current lead. It's supposed to be 90% down from the top of the screen, but it looks more like 95%. I could be wrong though

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > (.90*document.documentElement.clientHeight))
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0vw',
  'margin-top': '0vw'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 'auto',
  'margin-top': '90vh',
  'margin-bottom': '-90vh',
      });
  }
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">

<div id="getFixed">
 <div>
  <div style="float: left; display: inline-block; z-index: 1; width: 100%;text-align: center; padding: 0; "><a href="#section1"><h3>Link</h3></a></div>

 </div>
  </div>
    <script  src="js/index4.js"></script>

  
  

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



</html>
```

The goal is that the Javascript should read the height of the viewport in safari on mobile accurately and the sticky header should attach seamlessly.

Comment: Have you tried `position: sticky; top: 5%;` pure CSS rules on the inner div?

Comment: I've been avoiding using position: sticky since it isn't fully functional across browsers. I tried it out though, and it doesn't seem to fix it. Thanks though.